# Phpmailer can't send email (Could not instantiate mail function.;)

Tags: function, email, phpmailer, sendmail, instantiation

My sendmail function:

```
    $usr = $user;
    $body_msg = $this->getBodyEmail($fields);
    $email_from = 'contato@mydomain.com';
    $email_name = 'Name';

    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->SetLanguage("br", "phpmailer/language/phpmailer.lang-br.php");
    $mail->setFrom( $email_from, $email_name);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject   = 'Contato';
    $mail->Body = $body_msg;
    $mail->addAddress($fields['email'], $fields['nome']);
```

Of course I hid the domain.

So I try the `$mail->send()`, but it will not work and the `$mail->ErrorInfo;` displays: "`Could not instantiate mail function.`".

This system used to work without SMTP, I do not need it.

**EDIT:**

I changed the SetFrom to From and FromName and it seems to have worked.

```
$mail->From = 'contato@mydomain.com'; 
$mail->FromName = 'Name';
```

What it can be?

Comment: I'd suggest checking the return value from the `setFrom` call, see if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the SetFrom to From and FromName and it seems to have worked.

```
$mail->From      = 'contato@mydomain.com';
$mail->FromName  = 'Name';
```